# why does ipython hang with theano

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, theano

I've been trying to run various configurations of neural networks over the past few days using Keras, Theano and iPython (through Spyder). For a few days the code ran well but then iPython started hanging. This was on exactly the same code that ran without trouble in the past.

I tried all sorts of remedies such as installing Anaconda updates and re-updating Theano to the 'bleeding edge' version. But to no avail.

Then I just tried to run my code on the Python console in Spyder instead of iPython and it worked like a charm (no pun intended :-)). Therefore my guess is that there's something wrong with my iPython installation.

So I have two questions: 1) is my diagnosis accurate and 2) whether it is or not, what could I try to remedy the problem?

My config is:

- 2015 15" MacBook Pro with El Capitan
- Python 3.4.4
- Anaconda 2.4.1 (x86_64)
- IPython 4.1.2

Thanks in advance,

Edit: Response to Ogaday's questions: It's difficult to provide a mimimal working example as it depends on a fair amount of pre-processing and also needs inputs from other neural networks which I've trained separately. 
And on your suggestion I did try to run the code on iPython from the command line and it works! So maybe something's wrong with Spyder?
Finally 'which ipython' returns //anaconda/bin/ipython.

Comment: Can you create a minimal working example of the code that hangs and the version of theano and keras you're using?

Comment: (Also, what happens when you run the code on the command line, and what is the output of `which ipython` on the command line?)

Comment: Thanks Ogaday, I've edited the question with responses to your queries.

Comment: How do you know the difference between a "hang" and computation that takes very long?  Can you use a debugger or `dtruss` to see what the process is doing?

Comment: Thanks Brian. The reason I believe it's hanging is that Theano outputs accuracy and loss measures continually. That just freezes, so does the whole Spyder app. The OSX  application monitor says 'Python not responding'. Most importantly, none of this happens if I use a Python console inSpyder  or run iPython from the Terminal.

Comment: Well, it's annoying to have to avoid the spyder  IPython tetninal in order to run your code, but at least you have a solution for now. My hunch is that it's do with versions. I'll have a look at spyder later. What do you get for `!which ipython` in the spyder terminal?

Comment: Yes Ogaday,  it's a relief to have a solution as I am working on a coursework with a deadline in a couple of days. !which ipython also returns  //anaconda/bin/ipython.